# Why is the (print) output outside the loop different than inside the loop?

Tags: c

I am reading a file in C with the ESP32 and I am trying to put the lines and characters in a 2d-array. After I did this, I tried to print the array. First I did this inside the while-loop and after that, printed it outside the while-loop. The output from my print function in the while-loop is this:

```
[ 35 ][ 35 ][ 35 ][ 35 ][ 35 ][ 66 ][ 35 ]
[ 35 ][ 35 ][ 35 ][ 35 ][ 35 ][ 32 ][ 35 ]
[ 35 ][ 35 ][ 35 ][ 35 ][ 32 ][ 32 ][ 35 ]
[ 35 ][ 35 ][ 35 ][ 35 ][ 32 ][ 35 ][ 35 ]
[ 32 ][ 32 ][ 32 ][ 32 ][ 32 ][ 35 ][ 35 ]
[ 65 ][ 35 ][ 35 ][ 35 ][ 35 ][ 35 ][ 35 ]
```

And this is the output from after the while-loop:

```
[ 1073424916 ][ 1073424916 ][ -1688599997 ][ -961455512 ][ -724372320 ][ -1275106563 ][ 35 ]
[ 1073424916 ][ 1073424916 ][ -582559471 ][ -930149664 ][ 1510548983 ][ 1629549381 ][ 35 ]
[ 1073424916 ][ 1073424916 ][ 479218642 ][ 2091780050 ][ 1271856269 ][ -564334767 ][ 35 ]
[ 1073424916 ][ 1073424916 ][ -1348850970 ][ -972490428 ][ 1253901817 ][ 1424904752 ][ 35 ]
[ 1073424916 ][ 1073424916 ][ 731742849 ][ 1319147750 ][ -1130554592 ][ -2097033641 ][ 35 ]
[ 1073424916 ][ 1073424916 ][ 1671172429 ][ -1512979784 ][ -804137078 ][ -153094939 ][ 35 ]
```

This is the format of my txt-file which serves as the input

```
#####B#
##### #
####  #
#### ##
     ##
A######
```

The output from my print function after the while-loop is different and needs to be the same as the output from inside the while-loop. I don't know how it is possible. Maybe it has something to do with the memmory allocation. Why is every value at the end of a row how it is supposed to be? Can anyone help me find the problem and the solution?

```
    static const char* TAG = "Filesystem";
    FILE* f = fopen("/storage/test.txt", "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to open file for reading");
        return;
    }
    int height = 0;
    int width = 0;
    int currentChar;
    int** walls = (int**)malloc((height + 1) * sizeof(int*));
    while ((currentChar = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        if (currentChar == '\n') {
            width = 0;
            height++;
            printf("\n");
        } else if (currentChar != '\r') {
            walls = (int**)realloc(walls, (height + 1) * sizeof(int*));
            walls[height] = (int*)malloc((width + 1) * sizeof(int));
            walls[height][width] = currentChar;
            printf("%s %d %s", "[", walls[height][width], "]");
            width++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            printf("%s %d %s", "[", walls[i][j], "]");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++) {
        free(walls[i]);
    }
    free(walls);
    fclose(f);
```

Comment: Just pointing out that `walls = (int**)realloc(walls, whatever);` is always wrong. `realloc` may return `NULL`, and in that case, the memory has not been grown. However, you throw away your reference to the memory location.

Comment: You keep reallocating data inside the first loop.  AFAICS, as the width increases, you're losing previously gathered data.  You might be OK with a second `realloc()`, but your design is dubious.  Do you know how wide the input — how many number per line?  Or does that number vary per line?  What does the input data look like?  Where do you actually read the numbers anyway?

Comment: Without looking too much at the code, I'd suggest running the same code with the same input file on a linux system with `valgrind`. `valgrind` is a very useful tool to detect invalid memory writes and reads on the heap (which you are using). This is if you want fast results. However, why do you even want to dynamically allocate the memory in the first place? It's especially not a recommended practice on embedded systems where resources are limited and the penalty for memory fragmentation is high.

Comment: Aside: the hard coded reporting loop `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) { ...` shows you already know the extents. So you could have precalulated the array. But if not, why didn't you use `height` and `width` for the loops?

Comment: @Marco do you recommend to use a for loop first to count the height and width, so I can use those to make a loop for the array?

Comment: @WeatherVane I added the values 6 and 7 manually, because I thought maybe there is something with the height or width. But normally I do not know the values

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, ahh that makes sense. I flash a txt file on my esp. In that file there is a maze from width x and height y. Hastags are walls, spaces are routes, and we have a start and end point

Comment: So is it better to first loop through the file to get the height and width, and after that a new loop to read the file and put it in an array?

Comment: Knowing the shape of the data certainly helps — you can add new rows easily enough, but unless all rows are the same length, you will need to track how many numbers are in each row.  Showing a sample of the input data would be helpful — it isn't fair to make us guess.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).  Sample data is important!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for your feedback. I added it in the question.